Captioning an average of image set (instead of individial pictures)
I'm looking for a captioning model/tool that would be able to describe a group of images in a single sentence. Alternatively, I need a way to conceptually average a group of images before feeding that "concept" (presumably a feature vector) to a regular captioning model.
Why?
For training dataset curation. It would be beneficial to test the trained generation model on a prompt that would fit it as a whole instead of selecting captions of single images or trying to find what's common among them. Moreover, this would also allow to produce a single negative prompt to test how model behaves on out of scope prompts.
What I've done so far: I've modified an existing CLIP+BLIP interrogator to work with image sets. However, while CLIP captioning allows averaging image features before using them to choose the best caption, it's far less accurate than captions produced by BLIP, which only works with single images. I need a model that would take in feature vectors like CLIP so I can preprocess them.

This is the fourth time I'm asking this question in different SEs and every time I'm either ignored entirely or my question is closed without any help. I'm disappointed in this site, I've done my research, I built a prototype, everything checks out and yet I'm being given the middle finger.
